# Codeigniter htaccess Url rewriting

Tags: .htaccess, codeigniter, mod-rewrite

When I hit this URL:

http://dev.project.com/my-site

it redirects me to

http://dev.project.com/my-site/en.

I would like to remove the "EN" suffix from the url but it should go to the "en" version. My htaccess is below - can someone help me?

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /my-site/index.php?/$1 [L,QSA]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: There's nothing in your rules that's redirecting to `/my-site/en`, so maybe the issue is in your php scripts?

Answer (score 0):

try this .htacess

```
# Remove trailing slash
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s(.+?)/+[?\s]
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/$ /$1 [R=301,L]

# To externally redirect /dir/file.php to /dir/file
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+(?:index)?(.*?)\.php[\s?] [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [R=301,L,NE]

# Don't require .php extension to load php page
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /$1.php [L]
```